# Logicpuzzle: Row and Column size

Tags: logicpuzzle

I wanted to make a chaos sudoku using `logicpuzzle`. Now the examples helped a lot, but I really do not understand how to change the row and column size, everything is always 5 by 5. Does anyone know how to change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [package documentation](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/logicpuzzle/logicpuzzle.pdf), Section "2.2.1.1 Options":

`width [5.1cm]` sets the width of the minipage, in which the grid is typeset.

`scale [1]` scales the size of the grid in the minipage.

`fontsize [Large]` specifies the size of the numbers next to the grid.
Here, the usual LATEX sizes are used. Possible values: `tiny`, `scriptsize`,
`footnotesize`, `small`, `normalsize`, `large`, `Large`, `LARGE`, `huge`, `Huge`

Using these options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}

\begin{document}
Example with standard dimension (from the manual):
\begin{center}
\begin{chaossudoku}
    \chaossudokucell{1}{1}{3}
    \chaossudokucell{1}{5}{4}
    \chaossudokucell{3}{2}{4}
    \chaossudokucell{4}{2}{5}
    \chaossudokucell{5}{5}{2}
    \begin{puzzlebackground}
        \fillarea{orange}{(1,1)--(1,2)--(2,2)--(2,3)--(4,3)--(4,1)
            --(1,1)}
        \fillarea{pink!30}{(1,2)--(1,6)--(3,6)--(3,5)--(2,5)
            --(2,2)--(1,2)}
        \fillarea{yellow}{(2,3)--(2,5)--(3,5)--(3,4)--(5,4)
            --(5,2)--(4,2)--(4,3)--(2,3)}
        \fillarea{cyan}{(3,4)--(3,6)--(6,6)--(6,5)--(5,5)
            --(5,4)--(3,4)}
        \fillarea{yellow!40}{(4,1)--(4,2)--(5,2)--(5,5)--(6,5)
            --(6,1)--(4,1)}
        \end{puzzlebackground}
    \end{chaossudoku}
\end{center}

Example with enlarged dimension:
\begin{center}
    \begin{chaossudoku}[scale=1.5, fontsize=Huge, width=7.65cm]
        \chaossudokucell{1}{1}{3}
        \chaossudokucell{1}{5}{4}
        \chaossudokucell{3}{2}{4}
        \chaossudokucell{4}{2}{5}
        \chaossudokucell{5}{5}{2}
        \begin{puzzlebackground}
            \fillarea{orange}{(1,1)--(1,2)--(2,2)--(2,3)--(4,3)--(4,1)
                --(1,1)}
            \fillarea{pink!30}{(1,2)--(1,6)--(3,6)--(3,5)--(2,5)
                --(2,2)--(1,2)}
            \fillarea{yellow}{(2,3)--(2,5)--(3,5)--(3,4)--(5,4)
                --(5,2)--(4,2)--(4,3)--(2,3)}
            \fillarea{cyan}{(3,4)--(3,6)--(6,6)--(6,5)--(5,5)
                --(5,4)--(3,4)}
            \fillarea{yellow!40}{(4,1)--(4,2)--(5,2)--(5,5)--(6,5)
                --(6,1)--(4,1)}
        \end{puzzlebackground}
    \end{chaossudoku}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]